Python - using parent's method from child's super() call
I imagine there are lots of similar questions, but I'm not sure how to search for this situation. Suppose I have the following code structure:
class Parent():
    def method(self):
        self.helper()
        print('Parent method')

    def helper(self):
        print('Parent helper')

class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        super().method()
        print('Child method')

    def helper(self):
        print('Child helper')

When I call Child.method(), the super() call runs Parent.method() as expected. However, from Parent.method(), the helper that gets called is Child.helper(). Why does this occur? How can I get this to run Parent.helper() instead?

Uhm, that's a weird question: when you do Child().method(), its call via super is equivalent to  Parent.method(self) - note self is still a Child instance. If you override a method but want to access its ancestor somehow, you can call Parent.helper(self) manually. But the main question is: what's your use case? Usually this is pretty much expected thing, overriding in inheritance results in modifying relevant behaviour. You can also use name mangling for that (rename helper to __helper everywhere and see what happens), but it's hardly what you should be doing. XY-ish?

The use case is that I would like to have the helper() method have different behavior when I call it depending on whether the instance is of the Parent or the Child class (name mangling isn't an option because the API expects there to exist a helper() regardless of the instance). At the same time, I would like the helper() call from inside of Parent.method() to be Parent.helper() rather than Child.helper() regardless of the instance.

That said, your solution to explicitly call Parent.helper(self) inside of Parent.method() is exactly what I wanted. (If you add this as the answer I will accept it, but also would be grateful for general suggestions to better engineer this code instead of using this structure)

you can image that your code is actually like this after loading:
class Child(Parent):
    def method(self):
        # super().method()
        # the line above if same as:
        self.helper()
        print('Parent method')
        # end

        print('Child method')

    def helper(self):
        print('Child helper')

